# Why some tags in HTML are closed with <> or </>?

Tags: html, tags

I am doing some JSP coding in *Eclipse*, which is not the best IDE for auto-completion. I get many typos for elements that should be closed with `</>` instead of `</>` or the opposite.

Does anyone have a rule of thumb that helps me identify which ones close with `/` in the closing tag and which ones don't?

Some of you may tell me to code in a better editor like *Visual Studio* and copy code, but sometimes I am too lazy to copy a few lines of code. Hope you understand me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

each time you want use the tags you should start with <> and end it with </>
for example:

```html
<body>
  <h1> This is a head </h1>
  <div> This is a div </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Right. But self-closing tags like `<br>` and `<img>` don't need that. That was my confusion. Too late to delete it now :/

Comment: that absolutely right
i forgot the example for the self-closing because of that i didn't write it
have a nice day